# Posting Json to server in android using volley but getting only id in the server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I am using mongodb and node.js to build up a rest Api btw i am a beginner....So i fired up my localhost3000 using express but when i posted in android it gives only id and not the content..

like

```
[{"_id":"59f4bb537ddb610f0c94fcd0","__v":0},
 {"_id":"59f4bca47ddb610f0c94fcd1","__v":0},
 {"_id":"59f4c5ce7ddb610f0c94fcd2","__v":0}
]
```

Its giving only the ids in localhost:3000/api/vehicles

My android mainActivity

```
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/vehicles";
   try{


  JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
  jsonObject.put("UserName" , "zaid");
  jsonObject.put("Password" , "passwords");
  final String mRequestBody = jsonObject.toString();

  JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
         jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           System.out.println(response.toString());
      }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

      }
  }){
      @Override
      public String getBodyContentType() {
          return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
      }

      @Override
      public byte[] getBody() {
          try{
              return mRequestBody == null ? null : 
            mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
          }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
           return null;
          }
      }

      @Override
      protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

          if(response.statusCode == 200){

          }
          return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
      }

  };

  Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jor);
      }
  catch (JSONException e){

    }
```

The node.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
Vehicle = require('./app/models/vehicle')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/codealong');
var port = 3005;

var router = express.Router();

app.use('/api', router);


router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // body...
    console.log('Processing......');

    next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.send('HELOOOOO ' + 'World');
    // body...
});
router.route('/vehicles')

    .post(function(req, res) {
        // body...
        var vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.make = req.body.make;
        vehicle.model = req.body.model;
        vehicle.color = req.body.color;

        vehicle.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            };

            res.json({ message: 'Vehicle as manufactured' });
            // body...
        });
    })

    .get(function(req, res) {
        Vehicle.find(function(err, vehicles) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(vehicles);
            // body...
        });
        // body...
    });


router.route('/vehicles/:id')

    .get(function(req, res) {


        Vehicle.findById(req.params.id, function(err, vehicles) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.send(vehicles);
            // body...
        }); // body...
    });

.delete(function(req, res) {
        // body...
        var id = req.params.id;
        Vehicle.removeV(id, function(err, vehicle) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            res.json(vehicle);
            // body...
        });
    })

    .put(function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.id;
        var veh = req.body;
        Vehicle.updateV(id, veh, {}, function(err, vehicles) {
            res.json(vehicles);
            // body...
        });
        // body...
    });


router.route('/vehicles/make/:make')

    .get(function(req, res) {

        var query = { make: req.params.make };
        Vehicle.find(query, function(err, vehicles) {

            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(vehicles);
            // body...
        });
        // body...
    });


///fire up //////////

app.listen(port);

console.log('server started');
```

So i need this is the app.js file which i edited in js

Comment: If that's the response from your express app then there's more likely a problem in that. Can you show the relevant code from your express app that handles the request?

Comment: added!! pls reply

Comment: The only POST route in your express app is for creating new vehicle and responds with `{ message: 'Vehicle as manufactured' }` not the array of ids. So you need to be more specific about your problem. Which route returns only ids?

Comment: Oh Sorry i am new to stackOverFlow .... when i post the vehicles it gets added to the get method...but when i use get method then it returns only ids